# Move Calendar Emails by class to Deleted Items

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-5.0

Not sure what seems to be wrong in my code. I'm working into a script that moves accepted calendar invites from inbox to deleted items. in my case for example i have 5 accepted calendar invites. script will loop to in each email items in the inbox folder and once it identifies email class is accepted calendar invite it will move it to the deleteditems folder. script works fine however there is always one accepted calendar left from the inbox. not sure why not moving all the items.

```
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)
$deletedItems = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder(3)
$a = $inbox.Items
For ($i=1; $i -lt $a.Count+1; $i++){ 
if($a[$i].class -eq 56) {$item = $a[$i]    
$item.Move($deletedItems)}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop, as indices start with 0 or use a foreach loop.

```
For ($i=$a.Count; $i -ge 1; $i--)
```

Comment: Hi Peter, Thank you for sharing . tried this but didnt worked. it moved other emails but there still one left